# Solve the initial value problem : $u_{xy}=6x^2y$ ,$u(x;0)=1-\cos x$ , $u(0;y)=3y^2$ .

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Solve the initial value problem : $u_{xy}=6x^2y$ ,$u(x;0)=1-\cos x$ , $u(0;y)=3y^2$ .

I was trying like this , there is a special solution for $u_{xy}=6x^2y$ : $u=x^3y^2$. And for $u_{xy}=0$, we can get $u(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$. But after substitute it the initial value , there  always has a constant in it. How to do it next?

Comment: @Mattos Note that $u(x;0) = 1 - \cos x$ doesn't work with your suggested solution which gives $u(x; 0) = -\cos x$. However, if you add $1$ to the RHS, it'll then work, i.e., $u(x,y) = x^3 y^2 + 1 - \cos(x) + 3y^2$. Now, $u(x;0) = 1 - \cos x$, plus $u(0; y) = 1 - \cos(0) + 3y^2 = 3y^2$.

Comment: The missing $1$ was originally just a typo. Now I've accidentally deleted my solution as well.

Comment: You just integrate \begin{align} u_{xy} &= 6x^{2}y \\ \implies u_{x} &= 3x^{2} y^{2} + f(x) \\ \implies u &=  x^{3} y^{2} + \int f(x) dx + g(y) \end{align} Then, $$u(x,0) = \int f(x) dx + g(0) = 1 - \cos(x) \implies f(x) = \sin(x), \quad g(0) = 1$$ which gives $u(x,y) = x^{3} y^{2} - \cos(x) + g(y)$ and hence $$u(0,y) = -1 + g(y) = 3y^{2} \implies g(y) = 1 + 3y^{2}$$ yielding the explicit solution $$u(x,y) = x^{3} y^{2} - \cos(x) + 1 + 3y^{2}$$

Comment: @Mattos I believe you should transfer your comment as an answer as it seems you've basically solved the problem.